# Ts - The type argument for type parameter 'TResult1' cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have these promises:

```
 this.personService.getPerson(this.person.id).toPromise()
            .then((person) => this.getAddress(person))
            .then(() => this.save())
            .catch(() => this.handle)
```

> this.getAddress(person) returns a AddressListDto
>
> this.save() return void

and im getting this error:

> The type argument for type parameter 'TResult1' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
>     Type argument candidate 'void' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'AddressListDto'.

Comment: It looks like `this.getAddress()` or `this.save()` return `void` (or you just forgot to return anything)

Comment: this.getAddress() returns  and AddressListDto, and this.save() return void

Comment: That's probably the problem. `.then()` supports chaining so when you return `void` than any other `then()` calls would not receive anything.

Comment: Have a look at `lib.es6.d.ts` where `then()` is defined in `Promise` class as: `then(...): Promise<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
this.personService.getPerson(this.person.id).toPromise()
            .then((person) => this.getAddress(person))
            .then(() => this.save())
            .catch(() => this.handle)
```

The return type *also* includes whatever `this.handle` is. One way to handle error

```
this.personService.getPerson(this.person.id).toPromise()
            .then((person) => this.getAddress(person))
            .then(() => this.save())
            .catch((e) => {
               console.log("Optional tracking", e);
               throw e;
            })
```

## More

You probably wanted to *call* `handle` anyways.